# What does the "R" and "G" in the R&G Department level stand for?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

Presumably, this is supposed to be the R&D Department, or Research and Development Department, but given that this is the Gungeon, I can't help but feel it must be some gun related pun.

I can't find any information on the wiki or anywhere in the Ammonomicon entries, so presumably it's just an ambiguous R&G Dept.  But if there is a meaning, what do they stand for?

Comment: Run & Gun? I think Research & Gun is equally likely, I think.

Comment: @RavenDreamer You know, that would actually make sense considering that's the whole gist of the game...

Comment: It could also be a play on "RNG"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That's some deep level stuff man, I didn't even realize that but it rolls off the tongue so well, given that the game is both run 'n gun and RNG

Comment: Also, Dungeon becomes Gungeon. That's another D & G swapped.

Comment: My first thought was the same as @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - "*RNG*"

Comment: My first thought is "Research & Gun-velopment" as a play on research & development. Sounds better than research & gevelopment to me.

Comment: I'll revise my previous hypothesis - it's clearly RNG (just like D&D is DND)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the official wiki](https://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/R%26G_Dept.#Notes), it's a play on

- "RNG" *(Random Number Generator, the thing people blame when randomness works against them)*
- "R&D Department" *(Research & Development, a common department in many companies)*

However, they give no source.  They also mention

> It is unconfirmed what the acronym actually stands for.